# Are there any conventions in F# for highlighting pure or impure functions?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, purely-functional

Are there any conventions used in F# to highlight functions that are pure vs having side effects?

I've seen that there is a Pure attribute in the Contracts namespace; but this looks to be a helper for CodeContracts. Do people even bother trying to highlight pure functions in F#?

Comment: Think about how you would identify impure functions and you might see how this gets complicated. i.e. functions relying on other functions or referenced functions done in other languages.

Comment: I've never seen any such convention and as Guy Coder points out it would be rather impractical for several reasons.

Comment: This is interesting  https://twitter.com/sforkmann/status/395710341415706624

Comment: @GuyCoder Just because it's complicated doesn't mean there isn't value in it.

Comment: I didn't say there wasn't value in it. I too would like to know them but didn't pursue to a proof of concept do to the complications. If you do find an answer or create the code I would be interested.